# DIV not being created from PHP when doing AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to call a PHP script in my main PHP file.Below is the Jquery/Ajax part of the main php file. The display_stationinfo.php is supposed to create the DIVs in the main but it isnt.

this is what I tried so far, im new to Jquery and AJAX. thanks in advance!

**working fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/52n861ee/ 
thats what I want to do but when I click on desk_box DIV, the toggle station_info DIV is not being created by my display_stationinfo.php script.

When I view source code both DIVs are supposed to be already created but only desk_box is.. what am I doing wrong?

**JQuery/AJAX part:**

```
<div id="map_size" align="center">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Display station information in a hidden DIV that is toggled
        //And call the php script that queries and returns the results LIVE
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".desk_box").click(function() {
                alert("before toggle");
                var id = $(this).attr("data")
                alert(id);
                alert($(this));
                $("#station_info_"+id).toggle();
                alert("after toggle");
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'display_stationinfo.php',
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function(result) {
                        alert("before result");
                        $("#station_info_"+id).html(result);
                        alert("result: " + result); //it shoes every DIV being created and not the one that I clicked on
                        alert("after result");
                    }
                });//end ajax
            });//end click
        });//end ready
    </script>
</div> <!-- end map_size -->
```

**display_station.php (script that I want to call):**

```
<?php
include 'db_conn.php';
//query to show workstation/desks information from DB for the DESKS
$station_sql = "SELECT coordinate_id, x_coord, y_coord, section_name FROM coordinates";
$station_result = mysqli_query($conn,$station_sql);

//see if query is good
if ($station_result === false) {
    die(mysqli_error()); 
}


//Display workstations information in a hidden DIV that is toggled
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($station_result)) {
    //naming values
    $id       = $row['coordinate_id'];
    $x_pos    = $row['x_coord'];
    $y_pos    = $row['y_coord'];
    $sec_name = $row['section_name'];
    //display DIV with the content inside
    $html = "<div class='station_info_' id='station_info_".$id."' style='position:absolute;left:".$x_pos."px;top:".$y_pos."px;'>Hello the id is:".$id."</br>Section:".$sec_name."</br></div>";
    echo $html;
}//end while loop for station_result
mysqli_close($conn); // <-- DO I NEED TO INCLUDE IT HERE OR IN MY db_conn.php SINCE IM INCLUDING IT AT THE TOP?
```

?>

Comment: Have you verified that your ajax call works and that html is returned?

Comment: yes, I checked the console, I put alerts everywhere and the alert(result) gives me all the DIVS that are being created.. its containing it. the problem is I dont know how to extract them.

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT coordinate_id, x_coord, y_coord, section_name FROM coordinates";
```

Is fetching every row from the table coordinates, is this what you want to do? Or do you just want to return only the row with the id the users clicked?

jQuery

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'display_stationinfo.php',
  data: { 'id': id },
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(result) {}
});
```

php

```
$id = $_POST['id']
"SELECT coordinate_id, x_coord, y_coord, section_name FROM coordinates WHERE coordinate_id == " $id;
```

Looking at you [example](http://jsfiddle.net/52n861ee/), I would also guess that the problem could be that you are returning a string and putting it inside the target div so that the finished div looks somthing like this:

```
<div class="station_info_" id="station_info_84" style="position: absolute; left: 20px; top: 90px; display: block;">
  <div class="station_info_" id="station_info_84" style="position:absolute;left:20px;top:90px;">
    Hello the id is:84<br>
    Section:Section B<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Instead of returning a string you could return a json object and append only data to the target div

php

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($station_result)) {
    $id       = $row['coordinate_id'];
    $x_pos    = $row['x_coord'];
    $y_pos    = $row['y_coord'];
    $sec_name = $row['section_name'];

    $result = array('id' => $id, 'x_pos' => $x_pos, 'y_pos' => $y_pos, 'sec_name' => $sec_name);
    echo json_encode($array);
}
```

jQuery

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'display_stationinfo.php',
  data: { 'id': id },
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(json) {
    $("#station_info_"+id)
      .css({'left':json.x_pos ,'top': json.y_pos})
      .append('<p>Hello the id is:'+ json.id +'</br>Section:'+ json.sec_name +'</p>');
  }
});
```

Comment: basically I have two DIVs. When desk_box DIV is clicked it has to toggle the station_info DIV. In that station_info it must contain the information to display (which is being queried from the display_Stationinfo.php). All divs are shown on screen. I just tested your code (I had to fix some of your typos) and still no station_info DIV is being created when I view the source code. this is what I want : http://jsfiddle.net/grt7cj43/

Comment: Could you paste what's returned by the ajax call?

Comment: sorry I gave you the wrong fiddle take a look, when you click on a box you will understand what I want: http://jsfiddle.net/xfuddzen/

Comment: return from where exactly?

Comment: What do you get from the php, what is in the result var?

Comment: it gives me all station_info DIVs that are created. around 200 of them since its being read from the database

Comment: There are two ways to do this then: One, you binds all the results to the DOM before you search for the correct div to show (like you do in your example). Or two, you search the database for the row you want and only bind that one to the DOM. I guessed that you wanted to do the latter.